# Convert xlsx with multiple sheets to html with formatting and colors in the sheets intact

Tags: python, html, xlsx

I have been trying to convert an excel file to html file with formatting and colors intact using python . I tried xlsx2html and other libraries too . But nothing seems to work . I am currently working on centos 7 . I want and html file which has css embedded in it or seperate files will also do.

I tried xlsx2html , pandas , openpyxl.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.